# Using Realm Swift soring issue

Tags: swift, realm

Here is sample codes :

```
let outstandingStudentIDs = ["BGHH2", "AGHH1", "DFGH", "DFGHJ"]

let realmResult = realm.objects(Student.self).filter("studentID in %@", outstandingStudentIDs)
```

the realmResult is not keeping the ordering by outstandingStudentIDs.

How to make a customized sorting and keeping the object type in Results`<Element: RealmCollectionValue>.` 
If cast realmResult to Array to sort, how to make it back to Results since using `notificationToken` to observing the result changes

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should be able to chain `sorted` into that result.</strike>

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#sorting***

```
let realmResult = realm.objects(Student.self).filter("studentID in %", outstandingStudentIDs).sorted(byProperty: "studentID")
```

---

**Long Answer:**

To do the custom sorting you require, you will need to use `sorted(by:)`.  Unfortunately this will return an array rather than a `Results` instance.

Usually a `Results` instance is evaluated lazily, unless you wish to sort it.  In that case, Realm will need to traverse the entire data set to ensure it's returning the objects in the correct order.  If you provide your own comparison function, Realm *must* assume that your code is "unsafe" and could potentially cause problems.

Example of something that would make Realm explode:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    _ = realm.create(Student.self, value: ["studentId": "1"])
    _ = realm.create(Student.self, value: ["studentId": "2"])
}
let results = realm.objects(Student.self).sorted(by: { (_, _) -> Bool in
    try! realm.write {
        realm.deleteAll()
    }
    return false
})
print(results)
```

This prints a friendly:

```
[[invalid object], [invalid object], [invalid object], [invalid object]]
```

**Short Answer:**

Pretty sure it can't be done, but I welcome someone to show a decent solution.

Comment: I wanna sort the result by outstandingStudentIDs sequence not studentID alphabetical ordering

Comment: I think using [sorted](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift7Results6sorteduRd__s8SequenceWd__8Iterator7Element_zVS_14SortDescriptorrFT2byqd___GS0_x_) should result in getting a `Results`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The sorting OP wants to do can't be done with that function, it needs a comparison closure.